# React native while adding one item id by onpress it adds all the item at once

Tags: react-native

can anyone tell me what can i do..i want to change the add button to remove button when one item added and again onpress remove ...add button will come..

function //

```
const [multipletest, setmultipleTest] = React.useState([]);
function addTest(crypto) {
setmultipleTest((state) => [...state, crypto.id]);}
```

map list //

```
{filterdData.map((crypto, index) => (
        <View key={index.toString()}>
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addTest(crypto)}>
                {console.log(crypto, "crypto")}
                <Text> Add</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logic might help

```
function Example() {

  // default state
  const [multipletest, setmultipleTest] = React.useState([]);

  const add = (crypto) => {
    let newData = [...multipletest];
    newData.push(crypto.id);
    setmultipleTest(newData);
  }

  const remove = (crypto) => {
    let newData = [...multipletest];
    newData = newData.filter((e) => e !== crypto.id);
    setmultipleTest(newData);
  }

  // map list
  return filterdData.map((crypto, index) => {
    // check crypto id already exist or not
    const exists = multipletest.includes(crypto.id);
    return (
      <View key={index.toString()}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => {
            // handle onpress either add or remove as per condition
            exists ? remove(crypto) : add(crypto);
          }}
        >
          <Text>{exists ? "Remove" : "Add"}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  });
}
```